# Multiple Table MySQL Join where i wish to join 1 particular table twice

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following tables in my database that records user errors as a log so i can see who has made errors and at what time.

log, users, errortype and timeperiod.

Users contains,

id|name 
1  David 
2  Mark
3  Darren

errortype contains
id | typeoferror
1    error type 1
2    error type 2
3    errortype 3

timeperiod contains
id | period
1     7am-11am
2     11am - 3pm
3     3pm - 7pm
4     7pm-11pm

and log contains

id | user | date | time | staff | typeofmiss | timeperiod | dateoferror  | notes
1  |  1   |1/1/15|11:23 |   2   |     2      |       3    |        1/1/15| blah

I would like the user column and the staff column both to link to the users table and the typeofmiss column to link to the errortype column and the timeperiod column to link to the timeperiod table so that when i have run a query it would return:

1 - David - 1/1/15 - 11:23 - Mark - errortype 2 - 3pm-11pm - 1/1/15 - blah

I have managed to get a query partly working, but i can't get the link the data from the users table twice i.e. for the user column and staff column, it returns the same name for both columns.
Is there a way to get this to workor do i have to get  the data out and then change the numbers to the names using php or something?

Thanks

Comment: I have multiple entries in the log and wish to return all the records, and in future i will limit these based on date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alias the tables and then specify the (aliased) columns to select.

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.user, a.date, b.name AS user_name, c.name AS staff_name, d.typeoferror
FROM 
    log AS a
JOIN 
    users AS b ON a.user = b.id 
JOIN 
    users AS c ON a.staff = c.id
JOIN 
    errortype d ON a.typeofmiss = d.id
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html

Comment: I have done this and it gives the desired outcome thanks!

Comment: Although i now have a problem, This query returns 113 results, but the there are 120 entires in the log table, any idea why this might be?